# How to use hostvars in vagrant env

Tags: ansible

I'm having trouble using hostvars to pass a variable to another host in a vagrant environment, the code I did:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

    config.vm.define "server_1" do |server_1|
      server_1.vm.hostname = "n1"
      server_1.vm.box = "centos/7"
      server_1.vm.network "public_network", bridge: "wlp1s0", ip: "192.168.0.50"  
    end

    config.vm.define "worker_1" do |worker_1|
      worker_1.vm.hostname = "n2"
      worker_1.vm.box = "centos/7"
      worker_1.vm.network "public_network", bridge: "wlp1s0", ip: "192.168.0.51"
    end

    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
      vb.memory = 1024
    end

    config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
      ansible.playbook = "t0a.yml"
    end
 end
```

## t0a.yml

```
---
- hosts: server*
  tasks:
  - set_fact: hello=world

- hosts: worker*
  tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ hostvars['server_1']['hello'] }}"
```

expected:

```
TASK [show] *******************************************************************
ok: [worker_1] => {
    "msg": [
        "works"
    ]
}
```

actual:

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************
fatal: [worker_1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVarsVars object' has no attribute 'hello'\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/home/kayke/Documentos/vm-vagrant/provision-ansible/centos/t0_tests/t0a.yml': line 8, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n  tasks:\n  - debug:\n    ^ here\n"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is a single playbook that targets both server and worker, matching on their host patterns, because that way there is only a *single ansible run*, versus what's happening now is that ansible is being run twice, once for each host. Thus:

```
- hosts: server*
  tasks:
  - set_fact: hello=world

- hosts: worker*
  tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ hostvars["server_1"]["hello"] }}"
```

and invoked at the very end, like you see here: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray/blob/v2.8.3/Vagrantfile#L177-L193

I haven't studied Vagrant enough to know if it will write out an inventory file for you, or what, but if you need an example kubespray is also generating an inventory file from all the known vms, too: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray/blob/v2.8.3/Vagrantfile#L69-L75

If you don't like that approach, you can also use [fact caching plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/plugins/cache.html#enabling-fact-cache-plugins) to cause ansible to write out the fact cache for the hosts in a way that the worker playbooks can read in, but as you might suspect, that's a **ton** more work.

Comment: I tried with these changes but continued with this message:
TASK [debug] ***************************************************************
fatal: [worker_1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVarsVars object' has no attribute 'hello'\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/home/kayke/Documentos/vm-vagrant/provision-ansible/centos/t0_tests/t0a.yml': line 8, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n  tasks:\n  - debug:\n  ^ here\n"}

Comment: Please update your post with those code snippets, as comments aren't designed to capture that much text. Also, just including the failure isn't as helpful as the steps leading up to it, as well as the way you are invoking it from your `Vagrantfile`

Comment: So it appears that [`ansible.limit = "all"`](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/ansible.html#ansible-parallel-execution) is the secret sauce to having the one ansible run see all of the hosts at once. After I did that, `hostvars["server_1"]["hello"]` did what I expected